# How to keep a vertice (or two edges) sharp (without crease) when Subdivision Surface modifier enabled?

Tags: modifiers, vertices, edges, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to make this car model but as soon as I stumble upon a panel with a sharp corner I have no clue what to do.

I would like to make this:
[image]

Into this:
[image]

Without using Shift + E crease because that creates a sharp edge on the curved panel. Is it even possible or it's not advisable to use Subdivision when modeling cars in general?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello what does it give if you create support edge loops? For example select the horizontal edge and bevel

Comment: Hi, the solution was provided by lemon but thank you for help too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extrude the vertex (just a trick...).

[image]

But you can also crease the vertex:

[image]

Comment: Seems like this is exactly it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Add support edge loops (for example you can select the edge and bevel):

[image]